# Defining relationship on association table with filtering

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

This example develops on the Parent/Child association table on the SQLAlchemy docs (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object)

**How can I define the 'son' or 'daughter' attribute on the Parent class to filter the association table to the appropriate child type table?**

I understand how the 'children' relationship works, but I would like to add extra conditionals to the relationship. I suspect this involves the use of `secondary` in the definition of relationship, but this is at the edge of my understanding of relationships in SQLAlchemy.

```py
    from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, ForeignKey, String
    from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

    Base = declarative_base()

    class Association(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'association'
        left_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('left.id'), primary_key=True)
        right_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('right.id'), primary_key=True)
        child = relationship("Child", back_populates="parents")
        parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")
        child_type = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('child_type'))

    class Parent(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'left'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        children = relationship("Association", back_populates="parent")
        # I would also like to define 'sons' and 'daughters' here

    class Child(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'right'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        parents = relationship("Association", back_populates="child")

    class ChildType(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'child_type'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = Column(String(50))

    son_type = ChildType(name='son')
    daughter_type = ChildType(name='daughter')

    dad = Parent()
    son = Child()

    dad_son = Association(child_type=son_type)
    dad_son.child = son
    dad.children.append(dad_son)

    daughter = Child()
    dad_daughter = Association(child_type=daughter_type)
    dad_daughter.child = daughter
    dad.children.append(dad_daughter)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering the association table in the secondary to only include rows of the type that you are interested in for each relationship seems to work:

```py
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'left'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Association", back_populates="parent")
    # I would also like to define 'sons' and 'daughters' here
    sons = relationship(
        'Child',
        secondary="join(Association, ChildType, "
                    "and_(Association.child_type_id==ChildType.id, "
                        "ChildType.name=='son'))",
        viewonly=True
    )
    daughters = relationship(
        'Child',
        secondary="join(Association, ChildType, "
                    "and_(Association.child_type_id==ChildType.id, "
                        "ChildType.name=='daughter'))",
        viewonly=True
    )
```

... but adding objects via those relationships won't work as they don't know how to construct the association object with the child_type, hence the `viewonly`. Also, I changed `Association.child_type` to `child_type_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('child_type.id'))` which is why that's different in the example.

The `Child`/`ChildType` thing stands out as a possible application of the ['Mapping Class Inheritance Hierarchies'](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/inheritance.html?highlight=polymorphic#mapping-class-inheritance-hierarchies) pattern, if you aren't locked into this schema, that might be something to explore.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am struggling to make this work, could you post the full code with the changes you made, imports etc?

Comment: Here's the full code: https://gist.github.com/5uper5hoot/9953e97e1350350ae07e099d9beea981

Comment: Here's an attempt at the Class Inheritance solution I mentioned too: https://gist.github.com/5uper5hoot/6a219a458fadc69738d49ee8fecb8f13